# Is there a way I can tell the type of SWF?

Tags: swf

We have inherited a number of SWF files that we need to convert to AVI, MPEG or WMV. When playing back the files using the Swiff player from GlobFX it includes video and audio. Having researched the subject for the past 2 days I am no closer to determining the type of file it is as well as if there are any open source alternatives to converting it to one of the mentioned formats.

Comment: `SWF` `!=` `FLV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are actually getting at here. They are swf type. That is all you really need to know. Flash files.

They can be converted to avi files with [SWF to AVI](http://www.swftoavi.com/) freeware.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant was that having read a number of articles, it was my understanding that you can have varying types of SWF e.g. video, animations, etc.